# Changing value in on item also changes in another item - RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

The problem is in the recyclerview, if the view in one of the items is changed then the view gets changed in another item. And it changes specifically in the 8th position after the position of the actual item that is to be changed. Say, I change the quantity or price of the item in position 1 then the quantity or price is also gets changed in position 1 + 8 = 9th item. I can't figure out why this is occurring since I'm simply changing the view in the viewholder position. If anyone faced this kind of problem or has any solution it will be helpful. Thank you.

**RecyclerView Layout:**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/product_recyclerview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
   android:visibility="visible"/>
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<ProductItem> productItemList;
    private Context context;
    private ExpenseActivityContract.Presenter presenter;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, ExpenseActivityContract.Presenter presenter, List<ProductItem> productItemList) {

        this.productItemList = productItemList;
        this.presenter = presenter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView productImage;
        TextView productName, add;
        EditText quantity, price;
        ImageButton plus, minus;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {

            super(v);

            productImage = v.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            productName = v.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            add = v.findViewById(R.id.add_product_btn);
            quantity = v.findViewById(R.id.quantity_input);
            price = v.findViewById(R.id.product_price_input);
            plus = v.findViewById(R.id.plus_qnty_btn);
            minus = v.findViewById(R.id.minus_qnty_btn);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                          int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.product_item_layout, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.productName.setText(productItemList.get(position).getProductName());

        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String input = holder.quantity.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(input)) {

                    holder.quantity.setText("1");
                }
                else {

                    double qnty = Double.parseDouble(input);
                    qnty = qnty + 1.00;
                    holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qnty));
                }
            }
        });

        holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String input = holder.quantity.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(input)) {

                    holder.quantity.setText("0");
                }
                else {

                    double qnty = Double.parseDouble(input);

                    if(qnty > 1.0) {

                        qnty = qnty - 1.00;
                        holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qnty));
                    }
                    else if(qnty >= 0.0 && qnty <= 1.0) {

                        holder.quantity.setText("0");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return productItemList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I see your code calling changing/notifying the adapter?

Comment: @RoShanShan I am not changing/notifying the adapter. I am using the `onClickListener` inside `onBindViewHolder`. I have the holder and the view. Simply changing the view in that position using the holder.

Comment: This is not the way to change your item ViewHolder inside RecyclerView. You should change the data and after that, you call `notifyItemChanged(position)` to notify the item changed to Adapter.

Comment: @RoShanShan Yes. You are right. I implemented the adapter according to that. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of nature of RecyclerView.

RecyclerView tries to reuse (recycle) already drawn items(viewHolders) when drawing new items.

Since you get `input` from view which is recycled, it already has a value and continues to increase/decrease from that value.

All you need to do is to `holder.quantity.setText(some default value);` in `onBindView` method OR store the input in your model.

Comment: Okay, I get the point. Since it reuses the viewholder, I will have to implement some logic according to that.

Comment: @ShafiulIslamSajib I edited my answer and tried to explain better.

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestion. Instead of changing the view directly, I changed the item values and used `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Adapter class just override the
***override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
// Return a unique view type for each item
return position
}***

Comment: Yes, the question is tagged "android" but it is also tagged "java" so I'm not sure if Kotlin code will help. I suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Also, you should learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so as to properly format the [Kotlin] code in your answer.